# Calling MRT Swath from IDL

Tags: modis, idl

Do you know how to call MRT Swath from IDL?

I would like to work with Modis L1B (MOD02HKM), read it, reproject, some processing and writing the results.

Answer (score 2):

The MRT Swath program has a command line interface, see [page 19 in the documentation](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/public/MRTSwath_Users_Manual_2.2_Dec2010.pdf) for usage. You can call it from IDL using the [SPAWN procedure](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/SPAWN.html).